# Mapping AngularJs component in routing when() method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to create my first AngularJS app.
But I can not understand why my routing is not working properly(i think there is some problem in my when() method and directory structure).
Here is my directory structure(*I have followed AngularJS standard naming convention*).
[Directoty Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnTnq.png)

```
-Home
--sidebar
---sidebar.component
---sidebar.template
--home.component
--home.template
--home.module
-menu
--menu.module
--menu-list
---menu-list.component
---menu-list.template
-app.js
```

**app.js**

```
    angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'menu',
  'home'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider
  .when('/menu-list', {
    template: '<menu-list></menu-list>'
  })
  .when('/home', {
    template: '<home></home>'
  })
  .when('/sidebar', {
    template: '<sidebar></sidebar>'
  })
  .otherwise('/home');
}]);
```

**menu.module.js**

```
angular.module('menu',[]);
```

**menu-list.component.js**

```
angular.module('menu')
.component('menu-list', {
    templateUrl: 'menu/menu-list/menu-list.html',
    controller: [
        function MenuListController() {
            alert("MenuListController Called");
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: can you tell/show the specific error ?

Comment: i is just redirecting to the home component

Comment: I dont know how <menu-list> in when() method works, I mean do i have to name it with template(html) or component name

Comment: problem is in the directory structure or when()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was I did not name component correctly. In angularJS to include the view in html we need to name component in **camelCase** and it will be included by **hyphen-case**

```
Component name: 'phoneList'
View name: '<phone-list></phone-list>'
```

**Example from [AngularJS-Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03)**

**app/index.html:**

```
<html ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  ...
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="phone-list.component.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Use a custom component to render a list of phones -->
  <phone-list></phone-list>

</body>
</html>
```

**app/phone-list.component.js:**

```
// Register `phoneList` component, along with its associated controller and template
angular.
  module('phonecatApp').
  component('phoneList', {
    template:'phone-list.html',
    controller: function PhoneListController() {
      //...
    }
  });
```

*Note:If any error or written badly feel free to Edit*

Answer (score 0):

Been a long time since I've tried using ngRoute but here's how my 'otherwise' statement differs from yours:

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
  });
```

The difference is here I pass in an object with the property 'redirectTo'. You can check this [article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2780-route-redirectto-will-pass-through-current-route-params-in-angularjs.htm) out as well.

Comment: what should be inside '<>' in when() method?  Should it be the component name or module name?